# Uncaught reference error - Stuck solving to get function working

Tags: javascript, html

What I am aiming to achieve is that when img_html is appended and the image is an error, the handleError function will run and append an image that actually works. Right now I am receiving this error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: handleError is not defined
at HTMLImageElement.onerror
```

Here is my code.

```
              (function($) {

      window.petMapDmaPopup = {
        dmaCallbackUrl: 'My API (Not Listed on StackOverflow)',
        imageDir: '../assets',
        data : {},
        target: $('.dma-popup'),
        targetData: [],

        init: function(data) {
          this.targetData = data;
          petMap.progressBarInit();
          var type = Object.keys(petMapFilters.animal);
          $.ajax({
            url: this.dmaCallbackUrl,
            data: {
              code: data.dma_code,
              type: type[0],
              year: petMapFilters.year
            }
          })
          .done(function(response) {
            petMapDmaPopup.data = response;
            $('.progress-bar').addClass('hide');
            clearTimeout(petMap.progressTimer);
            petMap.progress = 0;
            if(!Object.keys(response).length) {
              petMapFilters.generateErrorMessage('no_dma');
            } else {
              petMapDmaPopup.show();
            }
          })
          .fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
            console.log('Request failed: ' + textStatus);
          });
        },

        show: function() {
          this.reset();
          this.populateInfo();
          var type = Object.keys(petMapFilters.animal);

          if(type[0] == 'Canine') {
            this.populateTabs('dog', 'Dog');
          }

          if(type[0] == 'Feline') {
            this.populateTabs('cat', 'Cat');
          }

          this.target.find('.result-tab .columns:first-child .tab-link').addClass('active');
          this.target.find('.result-tab-content:eq(0)').addClass('active');

          this.target.slideDown().siblings('.popups-inner').hide();
          $('.popups-wrapper .popup-close').removeClass('hide');
          petMapFilters.popupTabs();
        },



        populateInfo: function() {
          var html = this.tplInfo();
          console.log(html)
          html = html.replace('[REGION_NAME]', this.data.name);
          filename = this.imageDir +'/dma/_resized/' + this.data.code + '.jpeg';
          html = html.replace('[REGION_IMAGE]', filename);
          this.target.find('.dma-info-wrapper').html(html);
        },

        populateTabs: function(id, name) {
          var items = this.data.avg;
          var title = 'Top 5 ' + name + ' Breeds';
          if(Object.keys(items).length < 5) {
            title = 'Top ' + Object.keys(items).length + ' ' + name + ' Breeds';
          }

          var res_div = this.target.find('.result-tab');
          res_div.append(this.tplTab(id, title));

          var html = [];
          for(var i in items) {
            html.push(this.tplItem(id, i, items[i].region, items[i].national));
          }

          if(html.length < 5) {
            var count = 5 - html.length;
            for(var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
              html.push('<div class="columns shrink" style="width: 225px;"></div>');
            }
          }

          res_div.parent().append(this.tplTabContent(id, html.join('')));
        },

        tplInfo: function() {
          return '<div class="region-section">' +
            '<div class="bg-red color-white st-shadow region-wrapper overflow-hidden st-rounded">' +
              '<div class="padding-30">' +
                '<div class="font_avenir_roman text_20 resgion-state">REGION</div>' +
                '<div class="h3 color-white margin-bottom-0 font_avenir_roman text_38_42 font-weight-bold">[REGION_NAME]</div>' +
              '</div>' +
              '<div class="img overflow-hidden st-rounded">' +
                '<img src="[REGION_IMAGE]" alt="">' +
              '</div>' +
            '</div>' +
            '<div class="row collapse align-justify color-aluminium font_avenir_medium text_24">' +
              '<div class="columns shrink"><span class="rn red">Region</span></div>' +
              '<div class="columns shrink"><span class="rn green">National</span></div>' +
            '</div>' +
          '</div>';
        },

        tplTab: function(id, title) {
          return '<div class="columns shrink"><a href="#dma-tab-' + id + '" class="tab-link tab-result">' + title + '</a></div>';
        },

        tplTabContent: function(id, html) {
          return '<div class="result-tab-content tab-section" id="dma-tab-' + id + '"><div class="row align-justify">' + html + '</div></div>';
        },



        tplItem: function(id, name, regional, national) {


          var image_name = name.replace(',', '').replace(/\s/g, '').toLowerCase();
          dogSource = /dog/dma/_resized/beagle.png
          var image_html = '<div class="st-rounded-12 img overflow-hidden">' + '<img src="' + this.imageDir + '/' + id + '/_resized/' + image_name + '.jpeg" alt="" onerror="handleError(this);">' + '</div>';

          return '<div class="columns shrink">' +
            '<div class="breeds-chart-wrapper flex-container align-bottom align-center">' +
              '<div class="breeds-chart">' +
                image_html +
                '<div class="flex-container align-bottom align-center line-chart-wrapper">' +
                  '<div class="line-chart text_22_32 font_avenir_roman font-weight-bold bg-red-light color-red-light" style="height: calc(25vh/100 * ' + regional + ')">' +
                    '<span class="text">' + regional + '%</span>' +
                  '</div>' +
                  '<div class="line-chart text_22_32 font_avenir_roman font-weight-bold bg-green color-green" style="height: calc(25vh/100 * ' + national + ')">' +
                    '<span class="text">' + national + '%</span>' +
                  '</div>' +
                '</div>' +
              '</div>' +
            '</div>' +
            '<div class="text-center chart-text text_22_32 color-aluminium font_avenir_roman font-weight-bold">' + name + '</div>' +
          '</div>';
        },

      function handleError(image) {
    image.onerror = "";
    image.src = "/noimage.png";
    return true;
}

        reset: function() {
          this.target.find('.result-tab').html('');
          this.target.find('.result-tab-content').remove();
          this.target.find('.dma-data-wrapper').removeClass('hide');
          this.target.find('.loader-wrapper').addClass('hide');
        },

        showLoader: function() {
          this.target.find('.dma-data-wrapper').addClass('hide');
          this.target.find('.loader-wrapper').removeClass('hide');
        }

      };

    })(jQuery);
```

Comment: _“Here is my code:”_ - that appears to be incomplete (_starting_ with `tplTabContent: function`, this could hardly be valid JavaScript), so show a _proper_ [mre], please. My guess would be, that you probably simply have a scope issue here - if you add event handling via `onXYZ="..."` HTML attributes, then the function must be available in the global scope.

Comment: Hi, thank you, sorry that I have not looked into this yet!

Comment: handleError is in your class and you are referencing it as a global

Comment: I have updated my code now. How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: What even is `handleError`? I (meaning Chrome) doesn't see it anywhere except in the text (not the code) and the error message. You probably need to define it somewhere.

Comment: Apologies - I have been working on this all day, and during altering my code for those who have asked I accidentally removed that function.

Comment: @AliShahVis You should include all related code. Right now you are missing the part that is actually calling that function. Where is that handleError being used?

Comment: Apologies @RainerPlumer. I have been working on my code and had accidentally removed that portion. It has been re-added now and I have included all relevant code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like "**this**" in your template context refers to the main jquery class, so your handle error should be part of that class.

e.g

```
tplItem: function(id, name, regional, national) {...}
handleError: function(image) {
    Note that image parameter is assigned "this" and it is not correct.
    image.onerror = "";
    image.src = "/noimage.png";
    return true;
}
//in your template string
onerror="this.handleError(this);"
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response. I am aiming to get it working and I have added it underneath my tp1Item: section as you have.  I was getting an error in 'function(image)'  stating an identifier was expected. I had changed the line to 'function handleError(image)'.  and my HTML to 'onerror="this.handleError(this);'. It is not working still.

Comment: @AliShahVis did you read my comment in that handleError function? You need to fix it yourself

Comment: I made a new script. Thanks my dude.